# WordPress / Avada Theme: How to globally change link style?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I like the link style used by wired.com ([example](http://www.wired.com/2015/08/ibms-rodent-brain-chip-make-phones-hyper-smart/)). Basically, the links are underlined in the theme color, and become "highlighted" in the same color when hovering.

I was wondering how I would go about applying the CSS for something like that with the Avada theme? That is, where exactly would I put the CSS so that it affects the content of all pages/posts, while also respecting the theme color set in the theme options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can either search Avada's stylesheet (style.css) for `a` tags and modify the CSS

**OR**

You can add your own CSS and use `!important` for every property

Comment: Considering how badly Avada has been made, he'll sure need `!important` and a stack of rules (Avada use a lot of css rules with `!important` - sometimes it even use `!important` on inline styles...)

Comment: I've only heard of the theme due to its popularity, didn't know it was so badly constructed

Comment: Hm, but that doesn't work. I did add my own CSS (in the theme options) for the `a` element (even without `!important`) - but it affects _every_ `a` element (even menu items, breadcrumbs etc.) OTOH, when I define it as a class in the CSS and manually assign that class to the actual links in my pages, it doesn't have any effect.

I was wondering where I would define the CSS that affects only the generic links in pages/posts, and not everything that is technically an `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

For the links within the actual text (and not globally, with every button and icon all together) it worked for me to add the custom CSS like this:

```
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But it also included all titles, so its not perfect

Answer (score 1):

Avada options -> search for link

OR

Avada options -> typography -> body typography -> enable link text decoration